# Representations of (opposite) non-associative algebras on dual spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, nonassociative-algebras

I want to better understand the relationship between representations on dual vector spaces and opposite algebras when the algebra being represented is nonassociative. Specifically, my question is: **does the dual space of a module over a nonassociative algebra induce a representation of the opposite algebra just like in the associative setting?**

Here is what I understand: In the associative setting, when an algebra $\cal{A}$ is represented on a vector space $\cal{V}$ (i.e. we have $\pi:A\rightarrow End(\cal{V})$), which has a dual space $\cal{V}^\ast$, this naturally induces an opposite representation $\pi^o$:

$u( \pi(a)v) = (\pi^o(a)u)(v)$

where $u\in V^\ast$ and $v\in V$. The representation satisfies $\pi^o(a)\pi^o(b) = \pi^o(ba)$, so it is said to be a representation of the opposite algebra, where the product $\times$ on the opposite algebra satisfies $a\times b = ba$.

Ok, so here is my question. Nonassociative representations exist, but in general you can't write $\pi(a)\pi(b) = \pi(ab)$ (because the representation is non-associative). **Is it nevertheless possible in general to induce a dual representation in a similar way on $V^\ast$, and show that it corresponds to a representation of the opposite algebra?**

**EXAMPLE:** Let me use the octonion algebra as an example. The octonions have a natural bi-representation on themselves that satisfies properties like $L_{ab} = L_aL_b + [L_a,R_b]$, where $L_a$ and $R_a$ are the usual left and right actions of the algebra on itself. The opposite algebra has a representation on itself that satisfies e.g. $L^o_{ab} = L^o_bL^o_a + [L^o_b,R^o_a]$. The representation space is just $V=\mathbb{R}^8$, so if we take the opposite representation to be given by the transpose we find

$L^o_{ab} =L^T_{ab} =  (L_aL_b + [R_a,L_b])^T = L^T_bL^T_a + [L^T_b,R^T_a] = L^o_bL^o_a + [L^o_b,R^o_a]$

where I have used the alternative property $[L_a,R_b]=[R_a,L_b]$. As 'expected' the representation on the dual space seems to reproduce the expected identity for the representation of the opposite algebra. But of course this is just 1 identity for one specific algebra - my question is more general: **in general is the representation induced on the dual space also the representation of the opposite algebra?**

Comment: Isn't $\pi(ab)=\pi(a)\pi(b)$ part of the definition of a representation? If not, what is your definition of a representation of $A$?

Comment: The operator product is associative, so in general $\pi(a)\pi(b)\neq \pi(ab)$ (but some $\pi(a).\pi(b):= \pi(ab)$ can be defined). Definition (Schafer): Let $C$ be a class of nonassociative algebras. If $A$ is in $C$ and $V$ is a vector space, let $av$ and $va$ be to bilinear compositions for $a\in A$ and $v\in V$. Then the Direct sum $A\oplus V$ is turned into a nonassociative algebra by defining the multiplications

$(a_1+m_1)(a_2+m_2) = a_1a_2 +(m_1a_2 + a_1m_2)$ 

for all $a\in A$, $v\in V$. If $A\oplus V$ is in C, then V is called a bimodule for A in C (i.e. A is represented on V).